# Plesk create subdomains and databases dynamically

Tags: php, plesk

I am trying to create subdomains and databases using PHP in Plesk. I am looking at their API documentation, but I can't figure out how to do both of these things, so if you could help me, it would be great!

Comment: What it a problem? You should create domain, then create subdomain and finally create database.

Answer (score 0):

a little bit later. To create a subdomain:

```
/usr/local/psa/bin/subdomain -c %subdomain% -www-root %subdomain% -php true -ssi true -d %domain%
```

The database I usually create directly to MySQL with CREATE DATABASE.

Answer (score 0):

There is no able to create database for subdomain, only for domain/subscription.
Here the API request:

```
<packet version="1.6.3.0">
<database>
<add-db>
   <webspace-id>2</webspace-id>
   <name>MyBase</name>
   <type>mysql</type>
</add-db>
</database>
</packet>
```

where webspace-id - it'a id of domain(not a subdomain) of your subdomain.

If you try to create db on subdomain, you will receive following response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<packet version="1.6.3.0">
  <database>
    <add-db>
      <result>
        <status>error</status>
        <errcode>1023</errcode>
        <errtext>This object can be created **only in a webspace**.</errtext>
      </result>
    </add-db>
  </database>
</packet>
```

So, first of all you need to get info about parent domain of subdomain:

```
<packet version="1.5.2.0">
<subdomain>
<get>
   <filter>
      <name>sub.domain.com</name>
   </filter>
</get>
</subdomain>
</packet>
```

Then get id of parent:

```
<packet version="1.6.3.0">
<webspace>
<get>
   <filter>
      <name>domain.com</name>
   </filter>
   <dataset>
      <gen_info/>
   </dataset>
</get>
</webspace>
</packet>
```

Then create database on parent using received id.